# CiviRules opens strange window after disabling rule

Tags: civirules

I'm experiencing strange behavior of CiviRules v1.12 (CiviCRM 4.7.14.)

If I **disable** a rule, an unrelated window pops-up. In this case, *Fundraising call report*. Why should it open a report, if I disable a rule? (screenshot added)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to a bad user context somewhere in CiviRules. And probably related to this issue: https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules/issues/78.

The obvious next question is when will it be fixed? There are a few answers to that:

1. as soon as someone with programming skills feels the need to contribute a fix, which will earn him or her eternal fame.
2. when one of the CiviRules customers pays me (or another CiviCRM partner) to fix it.
3. When I get to my monthly community time and it is on top of my to do list.

The latter one is possibly in december, the earlier ones are unpredictable for me :-)

Comment: Sprint for CiviRules issues now scheduled for June, I would recommend testing with release that will be done at the end of this sprint.

Answer (score 0):

The fundraising call report is not part of CiviCRM core, my best guess is that whichever extension it comes from is behaving badly, i.e. not playing well with CiviRules.

Comment: I believe that as a **Contact report** it is a part of CiviCRM core, is not it?

Comment: Not necessarily, anyone can add a contact report in an extension.